# Iterate over a map in selmer

Tags: clojure, selmer

I would like to iterate over a map in selmer, in such a way that allows my to print the keys as well as the values. As far as I can see this is not supported out of the box, so I have tried the following:

```
(defn mapper-tag [args context-map content]
  (when-let [map-data (get context-map (keyword (first args))
                           (get context-map (first args)))]
    (apply str (for [[k v] map-data]
                 (selmer.parser/render (get-in content [:mapper :content]) {:key k :val v})))))

(selmer.parser/add-tag! :mapper mapper-tag :endmapper)
(selmer.parser/render  "{% mapper m %}KEY {{key}} \n{% endmapper %}"  {:m  {:a 1 :b 1}})
```

I expect this to output something like 
`KEY a
KEY b`

But it outputs

`KEY
KEY`

Any pointers?

Comment: Your outputs don't match your code. Where did `"FFF"` go and, where does `"KEY"` come from?

Comment: Fair point, the example was cribbed from two separate attempts, and the template didn't match the output. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps in Clojure are seqs so you can just use selmer `for`:

```
 (selmer.filters/add-filter! :key key)
 (selmer.filters/add-filter! :val val)
 (selmer.parser/render  "{% for item in m %} KEY is {{item|key}} VALUES is {{item|val}}\n{% endfor %}"  {:m  {:a 1 :b 1}})
```

Answer (score 3):

Selmer's built-in `{% for %}` loop [allows for destructuring](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer#for), so you can pull out the key/value right there in the template:

```
(selmer.parser/render
  "{% for key,val in m %}KEY: {{key}}, VALUE: {{val}}\n{% endfor %}"
  {:m {:a 1 :b 1}})
```

Output:

```
KEY: a, VALUE: 1
KEY: b, VALUE: 1
```